# Grade of influence of variables over a function

Tags: functions

Having a generic function $f_{(x,y,z)}$, what kind of analysis (are there standard methodologies?) have to be made to determinate the impact of each variable ($x,y,z$) over the function $f$ so that, for instance, I can know $f$ upon which variable is more sensitive?

Comment: Partial derivatives? $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} $ estimates how "fast" the function value changes when you change *only* x, and similarly you have partial derivatives with respect to $y $, $z $.

Comment: @BurNorIf you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **rate of change** of a funcion of several variables $\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is "measured" by the **partial derivatives**, which are defined and calculated with the same rules used for the funcions of 1 variable $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, keeping constant the the variables not involved in the derivation.

For example for f(x,y,z) they are indicated with:$f_x=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x},f_y=\frac {\partial f}{\partial y},f_z=\frac {\partial f}{\partial z}.$

**EG** suppose $f(x,y,z)=x^2yz^3+xy+z$ thus:
$$f_x=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=2xyz^3+y$$
$$f_y=\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}=x^2z^3+x$$
$$f_z=\frac {\partial f}{\partial z}=3x^2yz^2+1$$

Since in general the rate of change depend upon the direction, for funcion of several variables $\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ the concept of derivative is extended in all direction by means of the concept of **gradient**, defined as the vector which has the partial derivatives as component:

$$\nabla=(f_x,f_y,f_z)$$

By the gradient we can calculate the **directional derivative** for every direction defined by a vector $\vec v$ by the doct product with the gradient, that is:

$$f_{\vec v}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\nabla \cdot \vec v$$

The direction for which the rate of change of is maximum is the direction of the gradient and the rate of change is the norm i.e."lenght of the gradient" vector.